# How is the memory managed for a thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, memory-fragmentation

I understand that .net threads are pretty heavy weight, consuming ~1MB of memory each (mostly for the stack). Now, if this was a user .net class I know that it is likely going to put most of the memory into LOH. However, since it is a core class, I am wondering what the behavior is.

The reason for this question is because I am memory profiling an (potentially long lived) application at the moment, and there seems to be a slow leak. I had noticed that VS is showing 33 threads (in various states, included stopped). I am wonder if the frugal usage of threads could be fragmenting the memory (along with a few LOH DTOs).

Comment: How are you profiling?  What tool are you using?  This sounds like guesswork... guesswork is no way to debug a memory leak.  If you have a profiler, profile with it - there should be no ambiguity about where the leak is coming from (if it exists at all).

Comment: @J... I know. It IS guesswork, hence I am asking for more information. I didn't say I IDENTIFIED THE SOURCE as being threads, I am asking COULD IT BE BECAUSE OF THREADING. As for profiling, I am using ANTS 7. Which does not give me ANY information about the memory usage of the threads.

Comment: Surely it does. Instance retention should show you anything that is rooted. Are you using any native code (external DLLs, etc?).  Is this C# or VB.NET or something else?

Comment: I honestly don't care about instance retention at all. The question is about memory fragmentation and NOT instance retention. In fact if what I am asking is confirmed, and Thread stacks are placed on the LOH then actually, proper instance lifetime management would exacerbate the situation. However I know for a fact that the threads are handled by the ThreadPool. J... no offence, but this is not a run of the mill perf question and is about deep understanding in how the ThreadPool interacts with the GC.

Comment: So why bring up the point about a slow memory leak.  It sounds like you are trying to troubleshoot a slow memory leak that we're not even sure exists - the opening question sounds like you are pointing randomly at memory fragmentation as the possible cause of your slow memory "leak".  If this isn't about a memory leak then why mention it?  If there is actually a problem then fragmentation due to managed objects - threads or otherwise - is extremely unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: You might, however, add some of your profiler data and related code. It would help to know what we are talking about; otherwise this is a rather broad and wandering question.  What are those 33 threads?  Did you create them?  Are you creating a lot of short-lived threads?  What is your application doing?  Are there a large number of short-lived allocations?  To be an answer to a specific problem there must be specific details.  If you want to learn about .NET's memory management, however, I'd probably say this is off topic and suggest a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread's stack is not stored on the LOH because the stack is not a CLR object. The thread's stack is allocated by the operating system when .NET asks for a new thread.

A CLR thread is a thin wrapper around an operating system thread.

If you really do have a memory leak, you can be sure that it's not in the thread objects themselves.